# Hibernate with Lucene search

Tags: hibernate-search

I would like to perform the search based on synonyms, words with spell mistakes and so on. Can somebody suggest a good example using the latest version of Hibernate Search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are really two things at play here. First the synonyms and then the spelling mistakes. For the former I recommend you have a look at *SynonymFilterFactory* and how to use [@AnalyzerDef](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#example-analyzer-def). Obviously you somehow need the synonym file to begin with.

The latter problem (spelling mistakes) is not so much of a indexing issue (as with synonyms), but more of a search issue. To cater for different spelling mistakes you can search using *FuzzyQuery*.